# How to store user entered values across a website using C#?

Tags: c#, global-variables

I am currently working on a website that will have a high volume of traffic on it. The website has only 4-5 pages on it but I need to pass values selected on page 1 over to page 2 where more values are stored and so on until the user gets to page 5 where all values are passed to a third party system using XML.

Currently I use a dictionary object with roughly 20 keys stored in a single session object to hold the values across the different pages. I do this because some of the values are not just simple values like 'name' or 'age' values but can be complex like holding a dataset of results from an XML call on page 2.

I have read everywhere that global variables are bad so I am wondering if there is an alternative to using Sessions for this example? I cannot use a database to hold these values because of the way some of the values need to be stored (i.e. my variables are not just strings/ints). If I was to use global static variables how could I ensure the global variables are unique for each user?

Thanks for your thoughts.

Rich

** Edit 1 **
I am storing the current sessions in ASP.NET Session State and not inproc. I am just trying to figure out if what I am doing is bad practice or just generally accepted as an ok way of doing things. For example on the second page I get a XML result that I store as a dataset in my session for use on page 3/4 of my site. Should I be store/passing this info another way?

Comment: I don't understand this "I cannot use a database to hold these values because of the way some of the values need to be stored (i.e. my variables are not just strings/ints).": can't you put anything into a database, XML, BLOBs.  You might stuggle to get one to store cola but...

Comment: I could store certain values in the database but I would rather not split user/site values between database and session if possible as that could be a mess to maintain. Ideally I would like to keep it all together. The users will not be logging in to this site at any point as it is just a site to make a quick purchase for a rental company.

Comment: I would consider rule no.1 is dont just blindly believe what you read somewhere that "global variables are bad", "arrays are bad" they are all actually false statements if you do not focus on situations. Based on situations they can be bad or good, because no logic is greatly fit for either optimized cpu speed or optimized memory usage, session variables reduce your cpu usage but increase memory overhead, and other storage can reduce memory but increase cpu usage, its all situational and knowing fundamentals are better then following any blog blindly saying this is bad !!

Comment: Yup, I'd be first to agree with you Akash. Just trying to get a feel for what other .net devs would normally do to overcome this type of obstacle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot use a database to hold these
>   values because of the way some of the
>   values need to be stored (i.e. my
>   variables are not just strings/ints).

You actually can. You can serialise you object graph and store it as binary column in the database.
Additionally you can have this functionality out of the box and still using SessionState.
Here is an article on how to [Store Session State in Sql Server](http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/3595766).

So I would recommend to use Session but store the session state in the database.

Comment: I should have made it clear that I am storing my sessions in the ASP.NET Session State already. I could move over to using the database to store these values if the site gets very busy in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are the right choice.  The "global variables are bad" argument is a good one, but it's describing **global variables**, not **session variables** and pertains to how you organize data being passed among methods within your application.  Storing data between pages can be done in only one of three ways:

1. Store the data in **hidden fields** or **cookies** (so everything gets passed back and forth for each page request).  You could do this by just serializing your XML and other fancy data, but it sounds like a terrible idea.
2. Store the data in a **database**, **flat file.** This is a fine idea, but you'd still have to do the serializing work yourself.
3. Store the data in a **session**.  This is exactly the same as option #2, except that C# is doing the serializing for you, and then saving the results in a flat file.

You do not have to do any work to separate the data of one user from another.  Every visitor gets a unique session, and the data you store there won't ever be applied to another user (excluding a malicious attack such as a hijacked session).

Answer (score 0):

I would think session is the appropriate place to put things that are relevant to your 'session'.  It *is* true that over-using/abusing session can bite you with excessive memory consumption, but the alternatives can be a bit slower, just depending.   Also, if you use SessionStateService or store the Session in SQL Server, you have slow-down in serializing/deserializing the session objects on each request.

You can use ViewState, but that means all of the data will get serialized to the HTTP Form, which means it will get passed back and forth on subsequent requests.  Also, I think ViewState gets dropped from one ASP.NET form to the next, so unless you are on the same form, that won't work.

You can store the data in the database.  One way is to have Session use SQL Server.  If I were to use a database for this problem, I don't think I would use session in SQL Server though simply because if you store it yourself, then you could recover previously entered data.